# Entity Framework 5.0 Get names of table columns

Tags: frameworks, mapping, entity

Does anyone know, how I can get the column names of an entity, as they are named in the database?

For instance I've mapped properties in a mapping class to certain column names:

```
public class BewegungMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Bewegung>
{
    public BewegungMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.TechnicalKey).HasMaxLength(200);

        // Column Mappings
        this.Property(t => t.TechnicalKey).HasColumnName("BWG_TechnicalKey");
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I programmatically get the mapped column names (e.g. "BWG_TechnicalKey") of the entity "Bewegung"?

Many thanks in advance.